# find relative extrema points of the function

Tags: calculus

Find the points of relative extrema of the following function on
the specified domain: $[-\pi,\pi]$ ,  $ f(x) = \sin(x) - e^x$
Now I tried finding points where $f'(x)=0$ that is when $\cos(x)=e^x$ but I didn't find any? just a little insight or hint would be helpful ?

Comment: There are two global and two local extrema. The first local extrema can be found by inspection. You will need numerical methods to find the second local extrema. Don't forget to check the endpoints.

Comment: @Moo so you are saying i need newton's method to find the second local extrema ?

Comment: Yes ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @mulaan22 I have made some edits , these make the mathematical notation easier to read and also I provide some basic spacing as well. You can use MathJax to make your post easier to read, more people will like your question if you can write the mathematics using MathJax.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon Thankyou for your edits. I am not quite familiar with MathJax yet but I'll try to use it next time.

Comment: @mulaan22 Yes, a good mathjax beginner tutorial was introduced [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33179/short-and-helpful-advice-on-using-mathjax-on-the-site) precisely for new people on the site, so that they can go easy and learn the basic and obvious things clearly and apply them easily. This will benefit you. Thanks for your kind reply.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you look for the non trivial zero of function
$$f(x)=\cos(x)-e^x$$ if you want an accurate solution, for sure you need to use Newton method.

If you want an *approximation*, use one single iteration of Halley method with $x_0=-\frac \pi 2$. This would give
$$x \sim -\frac{\pi }{2}-\frac{4}{3-4 e^{\pi /2}+\coth \left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)}=-1.2990$$ while the "exact" solution is $-1.2927$.

What you could also do is to consider that
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\sin \left(\frac{\pi  n}{2}\right)-e^{-\pi /2}}{n!}\left(x+\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^n$$ Truncate it to any order and use series reversion to obtain
$$x=-\frac{\pi }{2}+t+\frac{t^2}{2 e^{\pi /2}-2}+\frac{\left(2+e^{\pi }\right) t^3}{6 \left(e^{\pi
   /2}-1\right)^2}+\frac{\left(6-2 e^{\pi /2}+11 e^{\pi }\right) t^4}{24 \left(e^{\pi
   /2}-1\right)^3}+O\left(t^{5}\right)$$ where $t=\frac{f(x)+e^{-\pi /2}}{1-e^{-\pi /2}}$.

Making $f(x)=0$ as desired, this limited expansion gives
$$x=-\frac{\pi }{2}+\frac{50-210 e^{\pi /2}+455 e^{\pi }-536 e^{3 \pi /2}+376 e^{2 \pi }-144 e^{5 \pi /2}+24 e^{3 \pi }}{24
   \left(e^{\pi /2}-1\right)^7}$$ which is $-1.2932$.

Comment: Unfortunately we haven't taken Halley and newton's method yet. But thanks for the answer. I'll come back to this question once we learn these methods.